# SVN server with remote GUI administration

Tags: linux, centos, software-rec, gui, subversion

I have 2 Linux servers. One is Centos 5.5 another is Centos 6.
I want to install SVN server on both server separately.

1. Can anyone tell me which svn server has a good remote administration GUI.
2. Also it's supported clients should be compatible with MAC and Windows systems.

Both 1 and 2 are important

Please suggest.

Comment: Unix tools like version control system don't come as a all-in-one solution. This also applies for Subversion *servers* which don't come with GUIs. However, you might use some more general server administration tool like Webmin, which appears to provide a [Subversion plugin](http://webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?search=subversion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I' using now http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising as well:

http://www.svn-access-manager.org/downloads/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In the end SCM Manager was easy to setup and functional. http://www.scm-manager.org/